# Redirection is not working php

Tags: php, mysql

In the `crudindex.php` if any user login with admin and password admix, echo some information and redirect to crudview.php.
Here the issue is any user  who clicks the login button it redirects to crudview.php.

Requirement : For admin user it will redirect to crudview and others crudeditusr.php

2) DO i need to regenerate session id and put the code  for login page also?

3) The secretkey I can change it to any number?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "kkits996_ganesh", "", "kkits996_testmysql")  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

// Declare array for errors
$error=array();    
//-----------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------CSRF PROTECT--------------------//
//-----------------------------------------------------//

//generate a token/
function generateToken( $formName )
{   
    //secret_key change it
   $secretKey ='?@GEskki58668445744!Erpoejsj48';
   if ( !session_id() ) 
   {
       session_start();
   }
   $sessionId = session_id();
   return hash('sha512', $formName.$sessionId.$secretKey );
}

//check if the token is valid
function checkToken( $token, $formName)
{
   return $token === generateToken( $formName );
}

//Separate REGISTER AND LOGIN TO NOT BE CONFUSED//

//-----------------------------------------------------//
//---------------------REGISTRATION--------------------//
//-----------------------------------------------------//
if ( isset($_POST['register']) && checkToken( $_POST['csrf_token'], 'userFromRegistration' )  ) 
{
    //if the username required
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/',$_POST['uname']))
    {
         $error['username'] = "Username must have alphanumeric characters ";
    }

    //if password has less than 6 characters
    if(strlen($_POST['pwd']) < 6)
    {
         $error['password'] = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }

    //if password does not match
   if($_POST['pwd'] !== $_POST['cpwd'] OR empty($_POST['cpwd']) ) 
   {
         $error['passwordmatch'] = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
   }

    //if empty error array
    if( !array_filter($error) )
    {
         //trim data
         $username = trim( $_POST['uname'] );

         // Hash you password, never save PASSWORD AS PLAIN TEXT!!!!!!!
         // MYSQL! : Allow your storage to expand past 60 characters (VARCHAR 255 would be good)
         $password = password_hash( $_POST['pwd'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

         //if the id is autoincremented leave id
         //----------USE PREPARED STATEMENT FOR SQL INJECTION---//

         $query = 'INSERT INTO cruduser (username, password) VALUES (?,?)';
         $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->close();
         $con->close();

         //Redirect because we need to consider the post request from crudadd.php
         header( 'Location: crudaddusr.php' ) ;
     }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------//



//------------------------LOGIN as admin---------------------//

if ( isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
    if ($_POST['uname']="admin" && $_POST['pwd']="adminx")
    {
        echo $_POST['uname'];
        echo $_POST['pwd'];    
        $con->close();
        header ("Location: crudview.php");
  }
}

//------------------------LOGIN as Normal-----------------------//

if ( isset($_POST['login']) && checkToken( $_POST['csrf_token'], 'userFromRegistration' )  ) 
{
    //if the username required
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/',$_POST['uname']))
    {
         $error['username'] = "Username must have alphanumeric characters ";
    }

    //if password has less than 6 characters
    if(strlen($_POST['pwd']) < 6)
    {
         $error['password'] = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }

    //if password does not match
   if($_POST['pwd'] !== $_POST['cpwd'] OR empty($_POST['cpwd']) ) 
   {
         $error['passwordmatch'] = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
   }

    //if empty error array
    if( !array_filter($error) )
    {
         //trim data
         $uname = trim( $_POST['uname'] );

         // Hash you password, never save PASSWORD AS PLAIN TEXT!!!!!!!
         // MYSQL! : Allow your storage to expand past 60 characters (VARCHAR 255 would be good)
         //$pwd = password_hash( $_POST['pwd'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
         $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

         $con->close();

         //Redirect because we need to consider the post request from crudadd.php
           header("Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=".$uname."&spwd=".$pwd); 


//         header( "Location: crudeditusr.php?suname=$uname&spwd=$pwd");
     }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------//
//if (isset($_POST['login']))
//{
     //what ever you want
     //Use password_verify() and session_regenerate_id() 
     //to compare passwords and to generate a session id to prevent session fixation.

//} 
//?>

<!--HTMl PART-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>"Login Registration"</title>
        <!-- bootstrap link is downloaded from bootstrapcdn.com for css and js -->
        <!-- col-mod-6 col-mod-offset are bootstrap related-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo generateToken('userFromRegistration'); ?>" required/>
            <h2>Login Registration</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username : </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['username'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?> ">
                    <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Username"/>
                    <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['username'])) echo $error['username'];?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['password'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?>">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['password'])) echo $error['password'];?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password : </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 <?php if( !empty( $error['passwordmatch'] ) ){ echo 'has-error';}  ?>">
                    <input type="password" name="cpwd" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                    <span class="help-block"><?php if (!empty($error['passwordmatch'])) echo $error['passwordmatch'];?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-mod-6 col-mod-offset-3">
                   <button id="submit1" name="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
                   <button id="submit2" name="login" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Login</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any errors? there are many redirect functions  which one is not working?

Comment: You are echoing `$_POST['uname']` and `$_POST['pwd']` before attempting to send an HTTP header. You cannot send headers after you have outputted body content.

Comment: Also, every username/password entered will take this code path, as you have used the assignment operator (`=`) rather than the equality operator (`==` or `===`).

Comment: I have changed to ==. But still for user admin and pwd adminx its not redirecting to crudview.php.It is going to crudeditusr.php for this user.

Comment: Now its fine. changed to == and included the admin user check inside if ( isset($_POST['login']) && checkToken( $_POST['csrf_token'], 'userFromRegistration' )......

Answer (score 1):

This form won't even get posted because submit buttons are not of `type="Submit"`.

Moreover, you need to have a check to differentiate actions when `login` is clicked or `register` is clicked.

Your form seems to be a form of registration. Add action as `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in the form tag. For now, change

```
 <button id="submit1" type='submit' name="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
 Register </button>
```

This would post the form data on the same page and your check `register` check should work.

Comment: Currently the form is working i.e registration and login is fine. No issues. Only if someone login with admin and password adminx it should redirect to crudview.php.